# AWS Pinpoint campaign does not send notification messages to device

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase-cloud-messaging, aws-pinpoint

I have created a segment in AWS Pinpoint and i add device token to AWS Pinpoint through java code and the same reflects in AWS Console also.I have created a Campaign and attached this segment to my campaign but my device dont recieve push notification.I even used Test Messages Option in AWS Pinpoint console and i recieve notifications at that time (this i did to rule out f Applec certificate and FCM Access key id is not causing issues)

[image]
[image]
What should i do to recieve Notifications on my device

Answer (score 0):

my java code was updating a particular segment which i had configured in AWS Pinpoint.I commented that code and I started recieving notifications from AWS Pinpoint